# Leaflet geoJSON filteration clash with markerCluster and map.on zoomend function

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geojson

I would like to solve the problem of mismatch between geoJSON filter data and zoomend function.

I recently have managed my geoJSON filteration as per the example below:

http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/filter/filter.html

and incorporated it into my map.

Firstly I though, that it doesn't work well enough, as the `map.om (zoomend, function` seems to be broken, looking on the situation below.

[image]

But after a while I found, that problem applies to the markercluster as per the image below:

[image]

Now my code looks like:

```
     mdu = L.geoJson(data2, {
                            style: style2,
                            pointToLayer: pointVMToLayer,
                            onEachFeature: OnEachVMmduFeature,
                            filter: function(feature, layer) {   
                                return (feature.properties.Type == "MDU" );
                            }
                            })//.addTo(map);    
                                                //MDU data filteration
                                                var mduData =  L.layerGroup([]);
                                                mduData.addLayer(mdu);
                                                mduData.addTo(map); 

                                        document.getElementById("MDUNew").addEventListener('click', function(event) {
                                        theExpression = 'feature.properties.Status == "Issued" ';
                                        console.log(theExpression); 

                                            mduData.clearLayers();
                                            map.removeLayer(mduData);

                                        mdu = L.geoJson(data2, {
                                                style: style2,
                                                pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {

                                                    return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
                                                        color:'red',
                                                        fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.Type),
                                                        fillOpacity: 1,
                                                        radius: 8
                                                    })
                                                },  
                                                onEachFeature: OnEachVMmduFeature,
                                                filter: function(feature, layer) {   
                                                     return (feature.properties.Type =="MDU") && (feature.properties.Status == "Issued" );
                                                },

                                            });

                                            mduData.addLayer(mdu);
                                            mduData.addTo(map);
                                        }); 

                                        document.getElementById("MDUAll").addEventListener('click', function(event) {
                    theExpression = 'feature.properties.Type == "MDU" ';
                    console.log(theExpression); 

                        mduData.clearLayers();
                        map.removeLayer(mduData);

                    mdu = L.geoJson(data2, {
                            style: style2,
                            pointToLayer: pointVMToLayer,
                            onEachFeature: OnEachVMmduFeature,
                            filter: function(feature, layer) {   
                                 return (feature.properties.Type =="MDU");
                            },

                        });

                        mduData.addLayer(mdu);
                        mduData.addTo(map);
                    });
```

And the markercluster section like this:

```
      featuresLayer2a = L.markerClusterGroup({         // layer 2 Virgin Media MDU
                        spiderfyOnMaxZoom: true,
                        showCoverageOnHover: true,
                        zoomToBoundsOnClick: false,
                        disableClusteringAtZoom: 17,
                        iconCreateFunction: function(cluster) {
                            var childCount = cluster.getChildCount();
                            var c = ' marker-cluster2-';
                            if (childCount < 10) {
                                c += 'small';
                            } else if (childCount < 100) {
                                c += 'medium';
                            } else {
                                c += 'large';
                            }
                            return new L.DivIcon({ 
                            html: '<div><span>' + childCount + '</span> 
    </div>', className: 'marker-cluster' + c, iconSize: new L.Point(40, 40) });
                            },
                    });
                     featuresLayer2a.addLayers([mdu]); // if this whole part with .addLayers part is switched off, map works fine!
                        map.addLayer(featuresLayer2a);
                        console.log("Is geojsonLayer in markerClusterGroup? " + featuresLayer2a.hasLayer(geojsonLayer));
                        featuresLayer3 = L.markerClusterGroup({        // layer 3
                        spiderfyOnMaxZoom: true,
                        showCoverageOnHover: true,
                        zoomToBoundsOnClick: false,
                        disableClusteringAtZoom: 17,
                        iconCreateFunction: function(cluster) {
                        var childCount = cluster.getChildCount();
                        var c = ' marker-cluster3-';
                        if (childCount < 10) {
                            c += 'small';
                        } else if (childCount < 100) {
                            c += 'medium';
                        } else {
                            c += 'large';
                        }
                        return new L.DivIcon({ 
                            html: '<div><span>' + childCount + '</span> 
 </div>', className: 'marker-cluster' + c, iconSize: new L.Point(40, 40) });
                        },
                    });
```

The console says:

> leaflet.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_targets' of
>   null
>       at i.removeInteractiveTarget (leaflet.js:5)
>       at i._removePath (leaflet.js:5)
>       at i.onRemove (leaflet.js:5)
>       at i.removeLayer (leaflet.js:5)
>       at i.removeLayer (leaflet.js:5)
>       at i.removeLayer (leaflet.js:5)
>       at leaflet.markercluster.js:1
>       at i._recursively (leaflet.markercluster.js:1)
>       at i._recursivelyRemoveChildrenFromMap (leaflet.markercluster.js:1)
>       at i._mergeSplitClusters (leaflet.markercluster.js:1)   [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GmgV.jpg):

If I switch off the 2nd part of the markercluster code from `featuresLayer2a.addLayers([mdu]);` the map works fine. So what should I put in the `.addLayers` option?

Is there any chance to sort it out?

UPDATE:

If I remove this layer by `map.on('zoomend', function()`, then the result is the same as after switching off `featuresLayer2a.addLayers([mdu])`;

The `map.on('zoomend', function())` code looks as follows:

```
 map.on('zoomend', function() {
```

if (map.getZoom() < 9){

```
    if (map.hasLayer(regus)) map.removeLayer(regus);
    if (map.hasLayer(stonewater)) map.removeLayer(stonewater);
    if (map.hasLayer(infill)) map.removeLayer(infill);
    if (map.hasLayer(mdu)) map.removeLayer(mdu);
    if (map.hasLayer(featuresLayer2a)) map.removeLayer(featuresLayer2a); // removing the markercluster for mdu layer
if (map.hasLayer(job3)) map.removeLayer(job3);
    }
    else {
    if (document.querySelector("input[name=regus]").checked && !map.hasLayer(regus)) map.addLayer(regus);
    if (document.querySelector("input[name=stonewater]").checked && !map.hasLayer(stonewater)) map.addLayer(stonewater);
    if (document.querySelector("input[name=infill]").checked && !map.hasLayer(infill)) map.addLayer(infill);
    if (document.querySelector("input[name=mdu]").checked && !map.hasLayer(mdu)) map.addLayer(mdu); 
      if (document.querySelector("input[name=mdu]").checked && !map.hasLayer(featuresLayer2a)) map.addLayer(featuresLayer2a);  //adding this line doesn't help. COnsole says the same!
if (document.querySelector("input[name=bt]").checked && !map.hasLayer(job3)) map.addLayer(job3);
   }
  });
```

But I am still far from the solution. Can anyone advice how to solve it?